# Recovering My Workspace content when an employee leaves

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am a Power BI administrator using Power BI in Premium Capacity.  I'm trying to use PowerShell to create a tool to help with offboarding employees.  The business question is, "What happens to user's reports (in My Workspace) when the user leaves the organization and is removed from AAD?"

Having little experience with Power BI yet, I look to my old reporting system.  When the user is no longer in the directory namespace, their reports are only accessible by an administrator using special tools.  If a certain management process is run to tidy the system, profiles for all users who are no longer in the directory namespace are deleted.  Content is then unrecoverable.

When an employee leaves, sometimes their super-secret, hidden reports (stuff in My Workspace that nobody else can see, not even their boss or the Power BI admin) are actually important for ongoing work.  How do I get these reports to the boss?

So, my first question is, "How is this handled in Power BI?"  If it is similar, then please continue reading.  If not, please inform me regarding how I can review user's reports before they are gone forever.

I don't see a way to grant permission for one user to see a different user's My Workspace, so my second thought was to create a temporary workspace to copy the content from their My Workspace into.  Working through this, I see I can copy between regular workspaces and I can copy from my own My Workspace, but I can't copy from a different user's My Workspace (or even my own if I use the workspace ID rather than not specifying a workspace).

After several attempts to do this, I found https://github.com/Microsoft/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/examples/CopyWorkspaceSampleScript.ps1.  It comes pretty close and it's more complete than mine, so I updated it to find a specific user's My Workspace given their email address.  But when I run it that way, I get...

```
Copy-PowerBIReport : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
...
Copy-PowerBITile : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
```

...when I run the script under my login.  Looks like I don't have permission.

Is this related to https://github.com/Microsoft/powerbi-powershell/issues/65?  If I understand this correctly (and if the information is correct) it is saying that as a Power BI administrator, I don't have the `Report.ReadWrite.All` or `Report.Read.All` scopes.  I'll need to create an application to get an access token I can use to perform this function.  Is that correct?

Is there a way for me to grant myself the appropriate permissions to perform this task?

I'm also getting...

```
Remove-Item : C:\Users\myaccount\OneDrive - my company\Documents\PowerBI\pbi-copy-workspace-temp-storage is an NTFS junction point. Use the Force parameter to delete or 
modify this object.
```

...probably because the local folder where I'm working is involved with OneDrive or Documents or both(?).

Timing is also important.  When do I need to do this?  After they have left and before their account has been removed from AAD?  Is there a way to recover content after the user has been removed from AAD?

Comment: as I know there is no way to do that. "My Workspace" or "PersonalWorkspace" are for Personal use only (draft, unimportant stuff). That means you should force to move every important report to a shared workspace (This should be a bussines rule). After the user leaves, the simplest way is to activate his account/ reset password and loginin as "him", download what is needed then the close the account in AD;

Comment: "login as him"... As a Power BI Administrator, how can I impersonate a different user so I can see the system as they do?  Or is the only option to have the user's password?

Comment: only to have the user's password. Use your script in powershell to login as Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps#log-in-to-power-bi;
or do this "manualy" via web